# How to parse/extract a list of values from a deeply nested XML file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, xml-simple

**How can I parse/extract a list of values from an XML file with well nested values?**

I have tried XML Simple and I am only able to extract the first value from a list of over 10 values. I am trying to first select seriesName "Temperature" and extract the values under that group.

**This is the XML file I am parsing T124.xml** (I HAVE MADE THIS A DIGESTED AS ITS A HUGE FILE):

```
<chart caption="" subcaption="" palette="6" yAxisMinVal="11800" yAxisMaxVal=17800"xmlns="http: ">
<categories>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="6"/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="12"/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="18"/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="21"/>
<category label=""/>
</categories>
- <dataset seriesName="Temperature" color="003366">
<Set value=675.0"/>
<Set value=613.0"/>
<Set value=612.0"/>
<Set value=614.0"/>
<Set value=613.0"/>
<Set value=413.0"/>
<Set value=613.0"/>
<Set value=313.0"/>
<Set value=213.0"/>
<Set value=653.0"/>
<Set value=633.0"/>
<Set value=623.0"/>
</dataset>
<dataset seriesName="Precipitation" color="66CC33">
<set value="50.6"/>
</dataset>
</chart>
```

**Here is the Perl code I used:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use XML::Simple 'XMLin';
use Data::Dumper;

my $parse = XMLin('T124.xml',forcearray => ['value']);
#print Dumper($parse);

foreach my $dataset (@{$parse->{dataset}}) {
    if ($dataset->{seriesName} eq 'Temperature') {
        print $dataset->{seriesName} . "\n";
        print $dataset->{set}->[0]->{value} . "\n";
    }
}
```

**I would like to see the following output (shown below), however I am only able to extract the first 675.0 value ONLY:**

```
Temperature
675.0 
613.0
612.0
614.0
613.0
```

ETC...

Comment: Don't use [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) as it's [*outdated*](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE).  Instead use [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) so you can utilize XPaths to access deep nodes.

Comment: Is your source missing quotes for the temperature values, or is that a problem in the paste?

Comment: Hi Jim, The sources XML is at the top. I show the context of the file <chart>...</chart>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple script to extract the temperature data from your XML. I've included the XML source here because the source you provided seems to be missing some `"`s. I've used [`XML::Twig`](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) to parse the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = '<chart caption="" subcaption="" palette="6" yAxisMinVal="11800" yAxisMaxVal="17800" xmlns="http://">
<categories>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="6"/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="12"/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="18"/>
<category label=""/>
<category label=""/>
<category label="21"/>
<category label=""/>
</categories>
<dataset seriesName="Temperature" color="003366">
<Set value="675.0"/>
<Set value="613.0"/>
<Set value="612.0"/>
<Set value="614.0"/>
<Set value="613.0"/>
<Set value="413.0"/>
<Set value="613.0"/>
<Set value="313.0"/>
<Set value="213.0"/>
<Set value="653.0"/>
<Set value="633.0"/>
<Set value="623.0"/>
</dataset>
<dataset seriesName="Precipitation" color="66CC33">
<set value="50.6"/>
</dataset>
</chart>';

my $t = XML::Twig->new();
$t->parse( $xml );   # or $t->parsefile( $filename ); to read from a file

# this xpath finds all <Set> elements under the <dataset> element
# where attribute "seriesName" = "Temperature"
my @sets = $t->findnodes('//dataset[@seriesName="Temperature"]/Set');

if (@sets) {

    my $outfile = '/path/to/output/file.txt';
    open my $out, ">", $outfile or die "Could not open $outfile: $!";
    print { $out } "Temperature\n";
    print { $out } $_->att('value')."\n" for @sets;
}
```

Output:

```
Temperature
675.0
613.0
612.0
614.0
613.0
413.0
613.0
313.0
213.0
653.0
633.0
623.0
```

Comment: Thanks Much "i alarmed alien"  I replaced say with print and added "/n" to gain the same results.  You have saved me all the pain. That said, I am attempting this script using in and out files.  I want to push the extracted XML data into a CSV file but not sure how to do this with "twig".

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear again.  The print out file isn't the issue (though I will use what you've provided) its the in file (XML) parsefile syntax Im lost at. $t->parsefile( "T123.xml") I though would be correct but...

Comment: What happens when you do `$t->parsefile(...)`? The XML you posted was invalid, so I had to correct it before I could do any parsing. You may well have to do the same thing. NB: from the docs for XML::Twig: *"A die call is thrown if a parse error occurs."*

Comment: HI i alarmed alien,  I pasted the full XML into the script, had to reduce the content of the first line under <chart...> and it works fine. However when I attempt parsefile I get the following error: "you seem to have used the parse method on a filename (*XML::Parser::FILE)"

Comment: That warning only comes up when using the `parse` subroutine according to the source code. What code are you using?

Comment: my $t = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => 
                         { 'section/title' => sub { $_->print } }
                     )
                ->parsefile( 'T123.xml'); WORKED  THANKS i alarmed alien FOR YOU HELP

Comment: I AM SO UPSET NOW.  I DIDNT WORK I RAN THE WRONG SCRIPT. I ran the one with the imbedded XML content. The parse file still DOES NOT work. AAAHH! Looking at the code I submitted - why would that work...

Comment: Thanks 'i alarmed alien'. You were right, the XML file was the problem so I will adapt the script to clean the XML file then I can parse it - UNBELIEVABLE.  Thanks again  FYI I am using the parsefile()